# Retrieve a simple string from internet in android app

Tags: android, string, private

I have a simple question: I have a private comunity android app that is not in the market, so my question is when i do an upgrade to the app i want to have a button that makes the users of the app verify if theirs app is outdated..

So i want a simple way to retrieve a simple string from a file that i update to the web with the version of the app, next my app will compare the version that is in the file and the version that is currently installed on phone.

Can you point me some directions?

Store a xml in Dropbox and parse it? :S is there anything more pratic to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google: "Android php json" without the double quotes...

Comment: As simple as it can get: http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-php-json-tutorial.html

Comment: :D thank you json is everithing i needed Eheh. thank you 1 more time. (when i can vote i will vote you up).